# Controller parameter binding of complex type when the constructor contains a complex type

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, asp.net-mvc-routing, model-binding

I have noticed that my DTO class requires either a public parameterless constructor or non-public with [JsonConstructor] attribute when the constructor parameter contains a complex type, in order for it to be posted as Json to a controller action.

So, the action would be

```
[HttpPost]
public void Something([FromBody] TestClass test) {}
```

When the class looks as follows and I post Json `{  "SomeProp": true }`

```
public class TestClass
{


    public TestClass(bool something)
    {
        SomeProp = something;
    }

    public bool SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

Then the test object is properly deserialized and instantiated.

However, when I use a complex type in the constructor, then the object that gets to action is null, unless I add a public or non-public [JsonConstructor] parameterless constructor.

```
    //[JsonConstructor] does not work unless I uncomment the attribute
    private TestClass(){}

    public TestClass(TestClass otherTest)
    {
        SomeProp = otherTest.SomeProp;
    }
```

Can you let me know why it works like that? And also, is that a matter of JsonSerialization or model binding or both or none?

I want to create a unit test around all my DTO classes that ensures they can be postedl, so it would be good to understand what happens in the back.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin - well, the problem is sort of solved in the question - sadly, the question was not popular/not good enough for somebody to provide an explanation :(